# Default Onclick of child element in expandablelistview?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

This is the onclick listener for child element.

```
 getExpandableListView().setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            onChild_Click(parent,v,
                groupPosition,childPosition, id);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

It is working when click on the child element. Now I need to select the first child as default(inside onCreate() method).
For expanding group I am using this.

```
 getExpandableListView().expandGroup(0);
```

I tried these things for child element but it is not firing the onclick event.But when click on the child it is working.

```
 getExpandableListView().setItemChecked(1, true);
```

and

```
 getExpandableListView().setSelectedChild(0, 0, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all you got to set your expandableListView choice mode to single..
I'll show you:

```
expListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
expListView.setItemChecked(numberOfChildToCheck+numberOfGroupThatIsOpened+1, true);
```

if you want it to work properly you got to collapse other groups when one is opened.
next you got to set the backgroud drowable of expListView childs to use a selector.

Here is an xml file for a background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime">


    <item android:drawable="@drawable/selected_backgroun" android:state_activated="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/simple_background"/>

</selector>
```

There is a layout that is inflated by you to set as a view for a child items. You got to set

```
android:background="@drawable/name_of_your_xml_file_with_selector
```

if it's not that clear you can ask questions and i'll show you all with images
gonna look like this..
[image]
thanks.